# How to make images swap using the SPACE key in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Around 2 days ago I began trying to create a small program which would basically act as a presentation for my University interview. I have been trying to make it so that when you press the SPACE key, the image switches and goes to the next slide. Could anyone help me with this? (p.s. I don't have very much coding experience so my code may not be the best).
Thank you and I really appreciate any help.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
tk = Tk()
tk.title("How I prepared for BSc Cyber Security")
tk.resizable(width=False, height=False)
canvas = Canvas(tk,width=500,height=500)
canvas.pack()
tk.update
FirstPage = PhotoImage(file='First Page.gif')
image_id = canvas.create_image(5, 5, image=FirstPage, anchor=NW)
SecondPage = PhotoImage(file='SecondPage.gif')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bind command.

```
widget.bind("<space>", myfunction)
```

then you create a function that edits the widgets you need.

```
def myfunction():
    myImage.configure(file='Second Page.gif')
    canvas.configure(image=myImage) # might not be needed
```

You will have to create a way to cycle through the images but that should be a good starting point.